# How to split strings into columns

Tags: java

I have a list of Strings in single column. I want to make three columns from these string and then  print the ouput to another file. How do I do this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
File file = new File("f://file.txt");

try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My input data:

```
City
Gsk
Relocation
sripallu
here
jrajesh
gurgaon
unitech
StatisticsThreads
WizOty
LTDParsvnathK
Quotesby
newest
PMaashuktr
```

My expected output:

```
City      Gsk      Relocation
sripallu here      jrajesh
gurgaon  unitech   StatisticsThreads
WizOty   LTDParsvnathK  Quotesby
newest   PMaashuktr      Loans
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: How do you plan to split columns? What's the delimiter?

Comment: The delimiter for split or delimiter for output?

Comment: `My code what I tried` I cant see any logic for splitting the columns here. This is not a try!!

Comment: @NarendraPathai OP said splitting requires only one column

Comment: you cannot get away by just posting some code which does not even count for a try!

Comment: @RomanC yes I knw, bt I mean the present code is just a reader and just spills out everything on console. How is that a valid try?

Comment: @NarendraPathai nope, not a try

Comment: `"f://file.txt"` This could lead to exception instead use `"f:/file.txt"` **OR** `"f:\\file.txt"`.

Comment: I think the problem with data structure, the list contains only one column, but three required.

Comment: OP said "*the list contains a list of strings*" but it doesn't contain at all.

Comment: My suggestions are to scan the file to fill the data structure that could have records and columns then output it to another file.

Comment: ok ok I posted vague code as I tried to read the file contents. Sorry now I posted the input and the expected o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structured your requirement in class like Output and make a list of Output.

```
public class Output{
   private String str1;
   private String str2;
   private String str3;
   <geter & setter method>
}
```

...

```
ArrayList<Output> list=new ArrayList<Output>();
int i=-1; Output op =null;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = scanner.nextLine();i = ++i%3;
     if(i==0){
        op = new Output();
        op.setStr1(line);
     }else if(i==1)
        op.setStr2(line);
     else
        op.setStr3(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it a little:

```
File file = new File("f://file.txt");

try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int itemsOnRow = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print (line + " ");

        itemsOnRow++;

        if (itemsOnRow == 3)
        {
            itemsOnRow = 0;
            System.out.println ();
        }
    }

    scanner.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should actually try to implement it next time. If you fail but post the code that you wrote, then it's easier for the people here to help you.

Comment: write bad code isn't required just give him good suggestions what to do.